# Why am I getting a KeyError:0 when I make an api call?

Tags: python, api, keyerror

```
symbol = 'AAPL'
api_url = f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/{symbol}?apikey={FMP_API_TOKEN}'
data = requests.get(api_url).json()[0]
print(data)
```

I ran this code and it was working find but now when i run it I receive this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 symbol = 'AAPL'
      2 api_url = f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/{symbol}?apikey={FMP_API_TOKEN}'
----> 3 data = requests.get(api_url).json()[0]
      4 print(data)

KeyError: 0
```

Could there be a problem with api or is it a problem with my code?

Comment: Did you try taking a look on what `requests.get(api_url).json()` is?

Comment: json dictionary keys must be strings; they cannot be integers.  So in this case the key would be `["0"]`, not `[0]`.

Comment: @rafaelc Yes.  It prints out a dictionary within a list.  The reason I'm calling for `[0]` is to remove the list format and only print the dictionary.    @John Gordon the dictionary keys are strings.

Comment: Well, should be clear that, from the error message, It is not a list :)

Comment: For whatever reason, the API is returning a dictionary instead of the expected list.  We cannot say what that reason is.  Try looking at the response content to see if it contains a meaningful error message.